# Rasa http api for add multiple sentence for one intent

Tags: rasa, rasa-x

i need to add more than 10000 sentance through api

rasa-x provide an api for add new traning data https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/pages/http-api#operation/addData

problem is i can push data one by one.

another option is Replace training data in bulk https://rasa.com/docs/rasa-x/pages/http-api#operation/replaceBulkData

for that i need take all training example and updated with this new data.
this is not reliable for large number of sentances.

is there any other option avaliable?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried iteratively go through all sentences and add them one by one via HTTP API?